# Pass null to a method expects Long

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I have a Scala method that takes 2 parameters:

```
def test(x:Long,y:Int){}
```

On some occasion I need to pass null instead of long ... something like that:

```
test(null,x)
```

The result:

> scala> test(null,2) :7: error: type mismatch;  found   :
>   Null(null)  required: Long
>          test(null,2)

Why do I need to pass null?
Actually ,for some reason,I can't pass any default values.
Thus, I need such a null.

**Note:**I know that the solution would be making it Option.
However let's say I have no control over this method signature,can I do any work around?

Any ideas!

Thanks.

Comment: You could also use java.lang.Long

Comment: Scala's `Long` in fact maps to the JVM primitive type `long`. So, a Scala `Long` cannot be `null`, because primitive types cannot be `null`. (Don't confuse `scala.Long` with `java.lang.Long`!).

Comment: the problem here is that jdbc is java and databases store null values for nullable longs. If you pass them as 0L in the scala system, you're asking for problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can't change the signature, consider the mistake of [Thinking Option[Foo] is the only/most natural way to express a missing function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238744/1296806).

If the param to your function is a lower bound, then Long.MinValue might be a natural default.

If by "for some reason,I can't pass any default values" (whatever that could possibly mean) you mean you can't add defaults to the signature, and you're going the route suggested in another answer of adapting the method, you might as well change f(a,b) to g(b, a=Long.MinValue) or whatever before forwarding.

Instead of making clients of your adaptor method call g(b, None), let them call g(b).  You're not passing the Option to the underlying f(a,b) anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Null is a subtype of types which inherit from AnyRef, not from value types which inherit from AnyVal.  This is why you are not able to pass null in.  This corresponds to how, in java, you cant have a null of type long. (ignoring the boxed Long type).

However, this is an indication that the signature of the method should be changed to:

```
def test(x: Option[Long], y: Int)
```

which indicates that sometimes it goes no value for x.  Since we have this nice Option class to deal with just this instance, there is little if any valid reasons to use null values, where you are relying on developers remembering to check for null values.  Instead, with Option, the compiler will force you to take care of the fact that the value might not be there.

Comment: I totally agree that it should be as an Option.However,I can't modify the method signature.I know what I'm saying is un logical.. but do you know any work around !!

Comment: Then you need to explicitly deal with it BEFORE you make the call then.

Comment: Yes Dominic .. do you have any ideas how !!

Comment: If you have a method that needs to accept a null and cannot possibly accept a null, clearly something is broken.  Seems like you either need to figure out what Long makes sense or not call this method.

Comment: What I mean Echo, is just test for null before you call the method that takes just a Long (rather then a Option[Long]) and deal with the exception there. You could write a `test(x: Option[Long], y: Int) = { //test for null here, and THEN call your other test method }` In other words.... wrap the bad method with something that is a bit nicer.

Comment: Thanks Dominic .. that would answer my question.

Comment: Thanks stew for your assistance.

Comment: This is probably the best option, but it's a pain if you are dealing with Oracle's PLSQL Array artifacts. In the case of Oracle arrays I'd have to have Array[Option[Long]]] to make Long arrays work. The addendum to this is that for consistency I'd also have to use Array[Option[String]]] and Array[Option[BigDecimal]]] for Scala Objects that are true AnyRefs and didn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way to convert scala primitives to Java wrapper classes, is to use the static valueOf members on the Java Primitive wrappers. I had this issue where I needed to convert an Option[Double] to a java.lang.Double or null. This is what I did:

```
val value: Option[Double]
val orNull = value.map(java.lang.Double.valueOf(_)).orNull
```

Just passing literal null should work if you are calling a method that accepts java.lang.Long/Double/Integer