# How to easily generate longs with scalacheck?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

I tried

```
  val arbLong: Gen[Long] = {
    Gen.frequency((20, Arbitrary.arbLong), (20, null)).sample.get.arbitrary
  }


  "arbLong" should "be able to generate null values" in {
    forAll(arbLong) { (generatedLong: Long) =>
      println(generatedLong)
    }

  }
```

so it does generate a null for longs, however I get `NullPointerException` most probably because of `Long` cannot hold `null` what is the proper way to use an arbitrary long generator which includes `nulls`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala's `Long` cannot be null ([Pass null to a method expects Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637827/pass-null-to-a-method-expects-long)). If you want to represent `Long`s which may or may not be present then use either `java.lang.Long`:

```
val arbLong: Gen[java.lang.Long] = {
  Gen.frequency((20, Arbitrary.arbLong), (20, null)).sample.get.arbitrary
}
```

or `Option[Long]` (see [Generate Option[T] in ScalaCheck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799226/generate-optiont-in-scalacheck)).